# you JUST had to?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, expressions

I know that if we say 'I had to do something' it means that there was an obligation. For example- I had to be there at 11 a.m but I couldn't make it in time.

My question is about 'just had to.' As far as I from movies and tv shows we use 'just had to' mostly in two situations.

1) To talk about what I was supposed to do but I couldn't. It's another way of saying 'all you had to do was.' For example- *What's wrong with you. You just had to ask her out.*

2) To talk about something someone did which they weren't supposed to do. We use it mainly to scold someone. For example- *You weren't supposed to talk about the surprise birthday party. But you just had to talk about it! Now she knows what's going on!*

Please let me know if I understand them or not. Specially the second one.

Comment: In this context, it's only use is as an intensifier. You can replace it with *really*, and it would have the same meaning. (Neither of your interpretations are applicable. If you left out *just* altogether, the sentence would have the same essential meaning without it.)

Comment: I would say the first example ("you just had to ask her out") uses 'just' to mean 'merely'; asking her out should have been easy but the person addressed failed to do it.  If 'just' were omitted, that nuance would vanish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the second one? Is my interpretation correct for the second one? Do we use it to talk about something someone did which they weren't supposed to or to scold someone?